# Cortex m3: fatal error: inc/hw_ints.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gpio, cortex-m

I'm working with Cortex M3, Stellaris® LM3S6965  Evaluation Board. I'm trying to make a led on if I press a button. But it always gives me an error when while building.

In the program I basicly check the status of the button, with that I enable the led. I'm new to this, I tried searching but I really could not find something usefull.

Many thanks

My current program

```
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"

char rawInputActive(void);

int main(void)
{
    volatile unsigned long ulLoop;

    /* Enable all the GPIO ports that I use*/
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOE);

    /* Config the pins (input, output,..)*/
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);  // select
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTE_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);  // up
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTE_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);  // down
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTE_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);  // left
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTE_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);  // right

    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0); // led
    GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTF_BASE,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA,GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    /* Enable the clock for the GPIO ports.*/
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_1 | SYSCTL_USE_OSC | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
                       SYSCTL_XTAL_8MHZ);


    while(1)
    {
        volatile int iDelay;
        volatile int read;

        if(GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE,GPIO_PIN_1) == 0){
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_0); // Led select
            //ret |= 1;
            for(iDelay = 0; iDelay < 3000; iDelay++);
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, ~GPIO_PIN_0);
            while(GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE,GPIO_PIN_1) == 0){}
            for(iDelay = 0; iDelay < 3000; iDelay++);
        }

    }
}
```

The error I get while building.

```
GCC HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.6 2012q2\bin
    compile:
        [mkdir] Skipping C:\projects\new\PushButton\Debug\bin because it already exists.
        [mkdir] Skipping C:\projects\new\PushButton\Debug\obj because it already exists.
           [cc] Starting dependency analysis for 2 files.
           [cc] Parsing ..\..\cmsis\core_cm3.c
           [cc] Parsing ..\..\startup\startup_lm3s.c
           [cc] 2 files are up to date.
           [cc] 0 files to be recompiled from dependency analysis.
           [cc] 5 total files to be compiled.
           [cc] arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wall -ffunction-sections -O0 -g -c -DLM3S6965 -IC:\projects\new\PushButton C:\projects\new\PushButton\main.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\sysctl.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\gpio.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\interrupt.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\cpu.c
           [cc] C:\projects\new\PushButton\main.c:21:26: fatal error: inc/hw_types.h: No such file or directory
           [cc] compilation terminated.
           [cc] C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\sysctl.c:32:25: fatal error: inc/hw_ints.h: No such file or directory
           [cc] compilation terminated.
           [cc] C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\gpio.c:32:25: fatal error: inc/hw_gpio.h: No such file or directory
           [cc] compilation terminated.
           [cc] C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\interrupt.c:32:25: fatal error: inc/hw_ints.h: No such file or directory
           [cc] compilation terminated.
           [cc] C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\cpu.c:26:27: fatal error: driverlib/cpu.h: No such file or directory
           [cc] compilation terminated.

    BUILD FAILED
    Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Should not `#include "inc/hw_types.h"` really be `#include <inc/hw_types.h>`? And the other includes likewise...

Comment: same error, I even tried the full path (#include "C:/projects/new/PushButton/lm3slib/inc/hw_types.h") but that is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-I lm3slib` to your compiler flags. That tells the compiler to look in that directory, which appears to be where the files are.

Comment: Now it says 

`[cc] arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wall -ffunction-sections -g-I lm3slib -O0 -c -DLM3S6965 -IC:\projects\new\PushButton C:\projects\new\PushButton\cmsis\core_cm3.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\main.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\sysctl.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\gpio.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\interrupt.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\startup\startup_lm3s.c C:\projects\new\PushButton\lm3slib\driverlib\cpu.c
       [cc] arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: lm3slib: No such file or directory

BUILD FAILED`

Comment: I guess that means you need to provide a correct path for that library... :) Sorry, been out most of the day, time for bed.